# Why am I getting this error in a just-started Angular2 app?

Tags: angular

I just started coding a fresh new angular2 app that I cloned from 
`https://github.com/angular/quickstart`

Why am I getting this error?

> app/app.component.ts(8,3): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ moduleId:
>   string; selector: string; templateUrl: string; directives: string[];
>   }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.   Object
>   literal may only specify known properties, and 'directives' does  not
>   exist in type 'Component'.

**`app.component.ts`**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  directives: [NavbarComponent]
})
export class AppComponent  {  }
```

**`navbar-component.ts`**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'navbar',
  templateUrl: `navbar.component.html`,
})
export class NavbarComponent  {  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove below line from **app.component.ts**

```
directives: [NavbarComponent]
```

And add it in **app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, NavbarComponent ], << add here
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

directives is no longer available from 2.0.0-rc.6

Comment: It was deprecated and has been removed in rc.6: https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/4a740f2

Comment: Thanks @echonax for sharing link